# Wordpress postcounter

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I get a value of how many posts I have? Is there a wordpress tag for that?

I want to use it in my theme like this: *Number of posts: 37*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a function that does that :

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
```

From the official [Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts) :

> The default usage returns a count of the posts that are published. This will be an object, you can var_dump() the contents to debug the output.

Or :
Again qoute :

> If you want to show the number of published posts use this code.

```
$published_posts = wp_count_posts();
echo $published_posts->publish;
```

I'm not sure which one is the right method, never tried before but seems like both will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you to show no of post in current page

```
<?php
$count = 1;
if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
layout of regular template file here
<?php $count++;
      endwhile; endif;
echo $count;
 ?>
```

Alternatively you can use as shown in Wordpress Documentation [wp_count_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts)

```
<?php
$count_posts = wp_count_posts();
?>
```